# printf and System.out.println not atomic (interacting strangely) on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, jvm, printf, system.out

I have a Java application writing to `System.out` from time to time. I also have some logging turned on (`-XX:+PrintCompilation -verbose:gc` ...) which is implemented natively in the VM. Both the native logging and calls to `System.out` eventually make a `printf` call to `stdout`.

However, on *Mac OS* (and just on this one, not on *Linux* and *Windows*) parts of the printed messages of the Java application are missing! Meaning I have a call like `System.out.println("Valid run.")` and it just prints `Valid ru` and the immediately one of the log messages of the VM. However, the missing `n.` is nowhere to be found.

I know the C standard does not specify `printf` to be atomic, however I though it is, or at least even if not, the missing `n.` must be somewhere else and not completely missing. Any ideas what this might be or how to debug this further?

Comment: Can you please provide some details about the version of JVM/JDK you are using? Please type on a terminal java -version

Comment: Did you try `System.out.flush()` after performing the write to check whether it was a flushing issue?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the output to a file and thoroughly looking for the missing `n`? Its disappearance could be an artifact of terminal display combined with hidden characters or carriage returns.

Comment: version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: flushing doesnt help. I already redirect it into a file, the problem occurs with and without redirection.